# Generating Mason output where the output lines should start with the % character

Tags: perl, mason

Using [Mason](https://metacpan.org/release/Mason) for generate some output from templates (not web).

Need generate an output from the Mason component where the output lines should start with the `%` character.

Because the `%<space>` at the beginning of the lines in the Mason component are executed as perl commands, currently I'm using:

```
<% $perc %> the remaining content of the line.
```

and the $perc is defined in the `%init` section as `my $perc = '%';`

The above works, but for many lines it is an terrible solution.

The question: **Is it possible somewhat generate Mason output where some lines contains the '%' character at the beginning of the line?**

Comment: have you tried %% as means of escaping the perly interpretation fo the line.

Comment: @LenJaffe Yeah, of course. That was the 1st thing what I tried. Not working. The only working solution is wrote an custom `<%filter>` :(

Answer (score 2):

Based on the conversation is the Mason mailing list, the only working solution is write an custom filter. *(unfortunately the "natural" double `%%` or escaped `\%` didn't works and probably will be never added into basic Mason syntax.)*

The following Mason filter works,

```
<%filter unesperc><% $yield->() =~ s/^\\%/%/gmr %></%filter>
```

e.g. from the

```
% $.unesperc {{
\%hello
% for my $i (1..3) {
\% test <% $i %>
% }
\%hello2
% }}
```

will produce output the wanted output.

```
%hello
% test 1
% test 2
% test 3
%hello2
```